# Column bind in Numpy 2 array and 1 matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays:

```
dvec =  np.repeat(0, k);dvec
mu   = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
Amat =  np.stack((dvec, mu), axis=1);
```

and a matrix

```
I = np.identity(k)
```

I want to column bind them in order to have one matrix

```
Amat =  np.stack((np.repeat(1,k), mu,I), axis=1);Amat
```

but when I do this python reports me

```
ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape
```

How can I solve this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use numpy.column_stack:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html

```
k=5
dvec =  np.repeat(0, k);
mu   = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
I = np.identity(k)

Amat=np.column_stack((dvec,mu,I))
```

Result:

```
array([[0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 2., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 3., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 4., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 5., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

This will answer your question:

```
np.hstack((np.repeat(1, 5).reshape(-1,1), np.array([1,2,3,4,5]).reshape(-1,1), I))
```

`np.stack` joins a sequence of arrays along a **new axis**.
So it requires them to have the same shape.

What you need is `hstack` which stacks arrays in sequence horizontally (column bind)